# a quadratic function with a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am studying Convex Optimization and my book says that if I have the function $y=x^TAx+2b^Tx$ and the solution $x^*=-A^\dagger b$, then $y$ can be reduced to $y^*=-b^TA^\dagger b$ $\quad$ ($\dagger$ is pseudo-inverse.)

But, I can't understand how $(x^*)^TAx^*$ can be equivalent to $b^TA^\dagger b$ in order to obtain $y^*$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from the properties of [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition) .
$$A^\dagger AA^\dagger=A^\dagger$$
Combined this with the fact that A is symmetric(and if its convex positive semi-definite but that's not required)  :
$(x^*)^TAx^*=b^T(A^\dagger)^TAA^\dagger b=b^T(A^T)^{\dagger}AA^\dagger b=b^TA^\dagger AA^\dagger b=b^TA^\dagger b$

Comment: I forgot that $A$ is symmetric... Thank you!